# Compile and Run with java.lang package alone

Tags: java

I have **jdk-10_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz**.I have untared this file.

I want to modify the JDK folder content such that when I compile a java code using javac bin file, it should throw a **ClassNotFoundException** when the java code contains a reference to any other package(such as java.io, java.util,..etc) other than "java.lang.*". I just want to remove all packages except "java.lang" package.

Even when the java file tries to get packages at runtime(using classloader) the classes should not be available. So simply I want to delete other packages except "java.lang" package.

I tried to find the other packages inside JDK folder but I am confused. I cannot find any solution directly by searching google. I also do not know whether deleting other packages might cause some any dependency errors.

Have anyone tried modifying the JDK folder content?

Comment: what is your actual goal?

Comment: You might need to create your own classloader

Comment: @Stultuske I am going to compile a java code collected as input from user. I should not allow user to use any other package other than "java.lang"

Comment: @AniketSahrawat is using a custom classloader a costly operation?. Since I will be executing this javac command for every request. Also Can I prevent loading classes at runtime using my own class loader?

Comment: Be sure to also check for unwanted classes in java.lang, otherwise people can just use a ClassLoader and get around any restrictions that you set by just loading new classes on the fly. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Comment: @kutschkem thanks for referring this.

Comment: Classes in `java.lang` depend on classes outside of `java.lang`, so you'll need the standard library to be accessible. And many classes in `java.lang` have risky methods, e.g. `java.lang.Class.forName`. I think class loading will never be the right way to restrict usage. The right tools for this sort of thing in the JVM is a `SecurityManager`. But if the code is really untrusted, you really shouldn't run it inside the same JVM as your application: fork a child process instead.

Comment: @DanielPryden I am going to run it separately as another user with less permission of accessing files. But anyway I want to restrict the usage.

Comment: @DanielPryden at least can I remove these two packages "java.io", "java.util" alone?

Comment: It depends on how you designed it. [Here you can get a quick start](https://www.journaldev.com/349/java-classloader).

Comment: @Vijay excluding `java.util` and `java.io` won't prevent filesystem access if you can still do `System.getRuntime().exec("cat /etc/passwd")` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

### please don't modify Java platform libraries by hand

Instead look at setting up **SecurityManager** with a custom policy, where you decide which classes (or even methods) you will allow to run.

Just create a [`SecurityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) which you can set using `System.setSecurityManager()` method within your runtime with your **custom security policy**.

This will allow you to capture exceptions thrown when violation of security policies happen, to return something useful to the user.

Have a look at this quick [intro to security managers in Java](https://blog.frankel.ch/java-security-manager/).

Comment: can I restrict System.setSecurityManager() method by setting in it?

Comment: sure. please also test and consider serialisation (object, serialised and submitted as encoded string), and URL class loading. I think by blocking access to all I/O you should be fine, but worth keeping in mind such attacks

Comment: Thanks a ton, @diginoise. That was helpful

Answer (score 0):

go to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk version\jre\lib, open rt.jar as zip,  and delete the packages u want

Comment: I cannot find the mentioned directory or rt.jar file. I'm using jdk-10_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz